# Python - Change and update the same header files from two different projects

Tags: python, python-3.x, project, data-analysis, file-management

I am performing data analysis. I want to segment the steps of data analysis into different projects, as the analysis will be performed in the same order, but not usually all at the same time. There is so much code and data cleaning that keeping all of this in the same project may get confusing.

However, I have been keeping any header files for tracking columns of information in the data consistent. It is possible I will change the sequence of these headers at some point and want to run all sequences of code. I also want to make sure that the header used remains the same so I don't erroneously analyze one piece of data instead of another. I use headers so that if a column order changes at any time, I am accessing the index of the data based on the header that matches the data changes rather than changing every instance of appearance of a particular column number throughout my code.

To accomplish this, I would like to file track multiple projects that access the SAME header files, and update and alter the header files without having to access the header files from each project individually.

Finally, I don't want to just store it somewhere on my computer and not track it, because I work from two different work stations.

Any good solutions or best practice for what I want to do? Have I made an error somewhere in project set-up? I am mostly self-taught and so have developed my own project organization and sequence of data analysis based on my own ideas and research as I go, so if I've done some terribly bad practice that would be great to know.

I've found a possible solution that uses independent branches in the same repo for tracking two separate projects, but I'm not convinced this is the best solution either.

Thanks!